# Struct linked list: is there a reason not to include all members in a node?

Tags: struct, linked-list

Let's say I need to create a linked list of products where I have to store the following data from each product: code, description, price, stock.
My first attempt would be to create a struct for the product type and a struct for the node type, like this:

```
struct product {
   int code;
   string description;
   double price;
   int stock;
};

struct node {
    product prod;
    node* next;
};
```

But is there a reason (other than readability) I can't condense everything in one struct, like this?

```
struct product {
   int code;
   string description;
   double price;
   int stock;
   product* next;
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically both are same.

But on the *design* perspective, the first one seems *far better* as it keeps the *product* and its *container* **separate**.

Note that any product is highly *unlikely* to be connected (using `next`) to another product, while having a container of product(s) whose products may not be at all connected to each other is more *obvious*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variables of type `product` outside the list, you should keep the wrapper `node`. If not, feel free to merge them.